# disable editing in cells without protecting worksheet vba

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I want to disable cell editing (direct typing into cell) but want to update that cell through code without protecting worksheet

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: A validation that can't be achieved???

Comment: when you say `without protecting worksheet` do you mean that you do not want to leave it protected after the code is run? meaning it will be in an unprotected state for the user.

Comment: Protection has a "UserInterfaceOnly" option which allows you to update using code with the typical Unprotect/Reprotect steps.

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:A10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents '// Assuming you want to keep it blank
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in your code whenever you want to change a value, just disable events before hand:

```
'// Will be deleted
Range("A5").Value = "TEST"

'// Will not be deleted
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("A5").Value = "TEST AGAIN"
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found a workaround. For whatever reason I couldn't get my macros to run correctly with the sheets protected so what I did is as a code to Pop up a message box for any cells that I didn't want the user to change. Then I added "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" to the beginning of any codes that needed to modify those cells and reset the alerts back to True at the end of those codes.

Comment: Instead of double quotes `"` use single back quotes `\`` for code. This would render as code `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.